# BASH: How to sort and remove duplicated data when columns joint together in a file with fixed format?

Tags: bash, sorting, duplicates

I have a file with fixed format shown below:

format:"<5integer><5char><5char><5integer><5float><5float><5float>".

```
    1SI      SI    1   0.411   3.644   1.684
    2SI      SI    2   3.554   0.039   3.705
    3SI      SI    3   2.337   1.867   2.694
    4SI      SI    4   0.004   0.760   2.471
    5SI      SI    5   0.677   2.056   3.134
   ....
14164H        H14164   0.322   1.045  10.580 
14165H        H14165   0.309   1.038  10.733 
14166H        H14166   0.608   0.522  11.250 
14167H        H14167   0.659   0.409  11.166 
14168H        H14168   0.396   0.316  12.068
```

You can see, each of the first four columns take 5 characters. There are five SI lines, and five H lines. Due to the fixed format, I am unable to remove the duplicated elements using below commands

```
sort -u -k 2,2 <filename>
```

I hope to remove duplicated elements(such as SI, H) only(not include atom id). The results would be like below:

```
    1SI      SI    1   0.411   3.644   1.684
14164H        H14164   0.322   1.045  10.580
```

Here, 1 in "1SI" denotes atom id, SI is atom name/element name.
Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any duplicated "elements".

Comment: Please post your samples in only CODE TAGS not in QUOTE tags in your post.

Comment: Please format the input and output so that we can see the proper columns. Also, why do some lines have 6 fields and others have only 5?

Comment: If you want to specify fields by their character position, use `-k 1.startpos,1.endpos`

Comment: @Barmar, this is the challenge I have. The third and fourth columns for H has been jointed together due to the fixed format which output by some simulation software. So you saw H14164 actually should be "H 14164". Here, there is not space to separate them.

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille, Thanks for your feedback. I improved my question.

Comment: So the first column is `<space>1416`, second column is `4H<space><space><space>`, third column is 5 spaces, fourth column is `H1416`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to match your comment above. Maybe you have an extra space at the beginning of each line? You really need to post this exactly correctly if you expect us to understand it.

Comment: @Barmar, Sorry about the confusion. Yes. You are right.

Comment: format:"<5integer><5char><5char><5integer><5float><5float><5float>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a specific character range as the key field, use the `fieldnum.character` syntax for specifying the key start and end. Using `1` as the field number, the character counting will start from the beginning of the line.

```
sort -u -k 1.6,1.15 filename
```

I tried this on your data and the result is:

```
14164H        H14164   0.322   1.045  10.580 
    1SI      SI    1   0.411   3.644   1.684
```

Except for being in the reverse order, this is the same as your desired result.

Comment: Thanks. It would miss the data for element SI.

Comment: Please update the sample data in the question so it matches the format you describe.

Comment: SI has small atom ID, thus, there are spaces between SI and atom ID, like "SI_____1"; However, H has large atom ID(5digit number), thus there is not spaces between H and atom ID, like "H14164".

Comment: My answer doesn't care about spaces. It just counts characters.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thank you so much for your help.